# displaying certain entries first based on custom field

Tags: custom-fields

I have a channel full of product entries. I have a checkbox custom field to mark a product as "popular". I want all "popular" products to display first in the list, like they are "sticky". But I don't want to use the default "sticky" option. Can I display all entries marked with "popular" custom field, then display the rest?

And i know I can use 2 channel entry tags, just trying to avoid it if possible.

Answer (score 2):

http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/channel/channel_entries.html#orderby

You can order by custom fields in the channel entries tags. It might mess up the order of the remaining entries though.

Comment: yea, I've been playing with those options, but I can't quite configure it to display the entries how I want. I want Ascending order, just want to show the "popular" entries first. If I do something like sort="asc" orderby="product_popular", my popular entries, which I added last, are still at the bottom of the list.

Comment: My "product_popular" value is "Yes" or nothing, whatever nothing registers as.

Comment: have you tried sorting by "dsc"?

Answer (score 0):

I have to do some more testing, but i think I got it with this...

sort="dsc|asc" orderby="product_popular|title"